# Sublist parameters are not supported in Python 3 for Hadoop

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am have problem fixing this problem for (lambda (x, (y, z)) : [(dest, z/len(y))

Error message
Sublist parameters are not supported in Python 3.xPylance

Position-only argument separator not allowed as first parameter

```
  print "Run 30 Iterations"
for i in range(1, 30):
    print "Number of Iterations"
    print i
    JoinRDD = AdjList3.join(PageRankValues)
    print "join results"
    print JoinRDD.collect()
    contributions = JoinRDD.flatMap(lambda (x, (y, z)) : [(dest, z/len(y)) for dest in y])  # 4. Replace the lambda function with yours
    print "contributions"
    print contributions.collect()
    accumulations = contributions.reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y)  # 5. Replace the lambda function with yours
    print "accumulations"
    print accumulations.collect()
    PageRankValues = accumulations.mapValues(lambda v : 0.85 * v + 0.15 / float(nNumOfNodes))  # 6. Replace the lambda function with yours
    print "PageRankValues"
    print PageRankValues.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 does not support `(x, (y,z))` where `(y,z)` would be the sublist parameter.

You may rewrite this line as

```py
contributions = JoinRDD.flatMap(lambda x, yz : [(dest, yz[1]/len(yz[0])) for dest in yz[0]])
```

Let me know if this works for you.